# AWS IAM role creation is failing

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have a DynamoDB table created in account A and a role created in the same account to perform some actions on it.

This role will be assumed by a lambda function deployed in account B. Right now I am only deploying the stack with the code above in account A. The stack for account B with the cdk for the lambda function will be deployed later. This is the relevant role code for the stack deployed in account A as below:

```
 self._ddb_table = ddb.Table(
            self,
            id,
            .
            .
            .
            )

 ddb_lambda_role = iam.Role(self, "ddb_lambda_role",
                                          assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
                                          role_name="ddb_lambda_role"
                                          
                                          )

        ddb_policy_stmt = iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=[
                'dynamodb:Query',
                'dynamodb:GetItem',
                'dynamodb:GetRecords',
                'dynamodb:PutItem',
                'dynamodb:UpdateItem',
                'dynamodb:BatchGetItem',
            ],
            resources=[self._ddb_table.table_arn]
        )

        ddb_lambda_role.add_to_policy(ddb_policy_stmt)
```

This gives an error saying: `The following resource(s) failed to create: [ddblambdarole...].`

There is no more information provided in the cli as well as the web console. Is there anything wrong you seeing with the role created above? How do I create a cross account role in the current account A that can be assumed by a lambda function in another account, if not the way done above?

**EDIT**

Adding screenshot
[image]

Comment: How does the failed event look in the web console? It will give you a reason for failure.

Comment: It gives the same string even in the web console.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Are you looking at the Events tab?

Comment: added it. Thats all there is.. Before this its all Create In Progress. Then this create failed, followed by roll backs.

Comment: it says, "Embedded stack" creation failed. Is there a child stack? Take the ' 
Logical ID', go to 'Resources' tab, and see if there is sub stack there. If so go to that stack and see if there is any errors in the 'Events' tab.

Comment: That's the error message for the whole stack. You need to add a screenshot for the specific resource's error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CloudTrail logs for events from `iam.amazonaws.com` there you will find the true reason for failure.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-log-file-examples.html#cloudtrail-log-file-examples-iam

Comment: Cloudtrail doesn't show reason for failure. It only shows the request to create a role with all the parameters passed in to create a role, but not any reason pointing to why it failed

Answer (score -1):

You should double check your role ability.

The role in account A which is assumed by lambda in account B must have the right trusted entity, in this case is the execution role of Lambda

The execution role of Lambda in account B must have the AssumeRole policy

I think all of you need here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Comment: At this point I am just creating a role. The lambda and its role has not yet been deployed in the other account. I am right now having the issue of a role not getting created in the first place.Once this role is created I think I will need to add another policy document that gives `sts:AssumeRole` to it so the lambda in the other account can access and assume this `ddb_lambda_role` role. The issue right now is the `ddb_lambda_role` itself is not getting created. Lets say I didnt need assume role, but a simple role that allows some operations on the dynamodb table. how to fix the code for that?

Comment: I dont have any experience with CDK, but I guess you can try to create 2 roles first, and at runtime you just need to attach your roles to the functions

Comment: Yea. Thats what I was trying to do. I can't create a role itself. The error doesn't even say anything beyond what I shared up in the post.

Comment: Where do you run your code? Maybe the place where you run your code or your IAM user does have permission to create roles

Comment: Then it would give another error saying access denied or something right? Its just giving no error and just saying resource failed to create. I have run similar code in other accounts in the past and it has worked.